# Javascript onresize Only Fires Off Once

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript that only fires off once and then doesn't do anything after resizing again.

I want it to run the function every single time that window is resized.

```
var ld = document.getElementById('loading'),
    w = document.body.clientWidth,
    m = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0],
    mw = w - 140;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    'use strict';
    ld.className += "loaded";
    setTimeout(function () {ld.parentElement.removeChild(ld); }, 500);
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        m.style.width = mw + 'px';
    });
});
```

Comment: @PHPglue They removed the loading icon, not the content of the page.

Comment: Their issue is totally unrelated to the ld element. The problem is with the resize event.

Comment: Yeah, ld is the loading div and m is the width of the element i'm changing.

Comment: It's not undefined, because the resize event works the first time, but after that it doesn't change again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ld = document.getElementById('loading'),
    w = document.body.clientWidth,
    m = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0],
    mw = w - 140;
```

Let's suppose the body had a clientWidth of 900 at the time. You now have the following variables in the current scope:

- `ld: <some DOM element>`
- `w: 900`
- `m: <main element>`
- `mw: 760`

When the page DOM loads, you bind the resize event:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    m.style.width = mw + 'px';
});
```

Which sets the css width of the main element to '760 px' every time the window is resized. It's always going to be 760. What you want instead is to get the width of the page every time the window is resized.

```
m.style.width = (document.body.clientWidth - 140) + 'px';
```

Comment: TYSM, I feel stupid now that I didn't realize that it was still using the original window width. The issue is now resolved. :)

Comment: Haha, no problem. We all make silly mistakes sometimes. Just avoid using global variables when you don't need them and you'll save yourself some trouble!

Comment: Just remember when you assign a Primitive value to a variable it's going to stay that way, without reassignment.